# Is there a word which connotes a sense of solidarity with one's self?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which can connote the sense of solidarity with oneself.  I've seen the awkward term ["self-solidarity" come up in the literature (example linked)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U7eIAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=%22self-solidarity%22&source=bl&ots=n8C2cQs3up&sig=uIPmt7SAdK44zOO5UYq_7ZvGaDQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi98vSO2oveAhWDN8AKHWZKCa4Q6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22self-solidarity%22&f=false), but it seems that there ought to be a better word.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 0):

**integrity**

adherence to moral and ethical principles; soundness of moral character; honesty.

the state of being whole, entire, or undiminished:

[www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com)